# i want use the result of the URL in a variable in JS

Tags: javascript

how i can use the result of this link in variable javascript :

```
https://aa.real-tv1.com/testtt.php?action=reseller_mapdash1
```

```js
let url = 'https://aa.real-tv1.com/testtt.php?action=reseller_mapdash1';

var myVariable;

fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then((out) => {

   myVariable = out;
   
   console.log([myVariable]);
   
}).catch(err => { throw err });

console.log([myVariable]);
```

so i know where is the problem now , when i use the variable 'myVariable'

outside a function i have Variable undefined

so how i can use the variabla outside a function ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: *How I can use the result of this link in variable JavaScript* - Give a proper explanation of what the problem with it was.

Comment: hello , this URL https://aa.real-tv1.com/testtt.php?action=reseller_mapdash1
 if you clic on it you see this result : {"code":"MA","value":"1"},    now how i can use this result in js variable,   like  : var mapData = [{"code":"MA","value":"1"}];

Comment: sxume me im not good in javascript but i need something like this :       $aaa = $.getJSON( "https://aa.real-tv1.com/testtt.php?action=reseller_mapdash1");

var myvar = [$aaa];

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have done most of the job, you simply assign the result "out" to a variable like so:

```
let url = 'https://aa.real-tv1.com/testtt.php?action=reseller_mapdash1';
let myVariable;

fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        myVariable = out; // here you assign to your variable
    })
    .catch(err => { throw err });
```

Comment: oh but when i use this variable its not work ,  `code` let url = 'https://aa.real-tv1.com/testtt.php?action=reseller_mapdash1';
let myVariable;

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
    myVariablr = out;
})
.catch(err => { throw err });

showMap("mapBubble", myVariablr, "Online Clients By Country");
`code`

Comment: i have tested the endpoint and it's returning a json with a trailing comma, and that's what's causing the problem

Comment: and how i solve that ?

Comment: this is a backend problem, it should be fixed on their part

Comment: can you check the code now ?